# Addition of sets ans subsets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The question is about adding the elements of 2 sets. I took all the elements and added them to get 182. But that is wrong, can someone please help me see why that is wrong.

Here is the actual question:

[image]

Comment: Since the union is a set, duplicates are not allowed, so make sure to add each value only once.

Comment: $A\cup B=\{12,14,16,18,20,22,26\}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given two sets $A$ and $B$, one can form a set from them that consists of all the elements of $A$ together with all the elements of $B$. This set is called the **union** of $A$ and $B$ and is denoted by $A \cup B$. Formally, we define

$$A \cup B = \{ x \text{ } | \text{ } x \in A \text{ or } x\in B \}.$$

(Note, $A \cup B$ is the set consisting of all elements $x$ that belong to $A$ or to $B$ or to both).

Now, in your case we have:

$$A\cup B = \{ 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 26 \},$$

so the sum of elements of $A \cup B$ is $128$.

Comment: So this means that we take all the common numbers from both sets and make them 1. I don't understand why you do that, could you please explain? Thank you, this is helping though!

Comment: We take all the common elements for both sets only once, but we have to take all their different elements as well. Simple, the reason why the union operate like that is in its definition. Try to read once again what I wrote... or see: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/statistics-probability/probability-library/basic-set-ops/v/intersection-and-union-of-sets

Comment: Thank you so much, that helped a lot.